# UITextField Custom Keyboard and Response to Device Orientation

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I'm trying to attach a custom keyboard to a UITextField, and the keyboard would respond to different view orientations (landscape, portrait, etc). In short, the issue is that while the keyboard does show up, when responding to view orientation when I rotate the device, the dimensions of the keyboard is all messed up, and I'm not quite sure how to set the keyboard frame/bounds correctly. Hope someone here can give me a hand!

Here is my design:

The keyboard is built from a subclass of UIViewController (from xib). There are two views: landscapeKeyboardView and portraitKeyboardView.

The keyboard is attached to the UITextField through the property "inputView".

The rotation of the keyboard view is done in the function:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientationduration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) 
    {
        self.view = self.landscapeKeyboardView;
    }else if((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
    {
        self.view = self.portraitKeyboardView;
    }
}
```

The rotation does occur, but the view dimension is all messed up after the rotation. I have also tried to manually set the frame or the bounds of the view of either self.view or landscapeKeyboardView or portraitKeyboardView, and none of them seemed to solve the problem.

Does anyone know how to work around this issue? Or is there a much better design pattern for custom keyboards?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to translate the CGRect for rotation. UIView has a number of instance methods for converting rects and points. It accounts for views outside the frame of another view (to find out how far below a UIPopover the keyboard rect is, for example) as well as rotation. c[onvertRect:fromView:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) is just one example, but they all start with 'convert'.